# set WebView in center horizontal

Tags: android, webview

I placed a gif image in a webview and I want to put the webview in the horizontal center. I tried this code 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" with relative layout  but that does'nt work

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
 <WebView 
  android:id="@+id/imgChargement"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

but it does not work
Can any one help me please !

Comment: can you add the whole layout code. cos this is not clear enough

Comment: <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/imgChargement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      />
    </RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you are loading an image I know, but I would start simple. Here is a way to load some text and center it horizontally.  You would do this in code after you inflate your layout.

```
// get a variable for the webview, then
imgChargement.loadData("<html><body  align='center'>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>", "text/html", null);
```

In otherwords, I am using `align='center'` to center the contents of the `WebView`, not the `WebView`.  Now, you could center the`WebView` in the layout, but if the contents aren't centered within the `WebView`, then you won't get the appearance of centering that you are looking for..

Furthermore, you can't just stick an image in the `WebView` and then have the have the `WebView` "wrap_content" (like you would when just laying out android views).  The "wrap_content' is ignored and the `WebView` width ends up defaulting to the parent's width. (You can use "wrap_content", but it doesn't size the view to the HTML content, as I think you are expecting it to do).

So, for your case, just replace the text inside of the body tags of my example with your HTML for your image, and see if that helps you solve the problem.

I am using the following XML and not using any centering attributes in the parent.

```
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/imgChargement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: @Mouna I think you should accept this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

to

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

of the WebView

Final Relative Layout will look like this

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/imgChargement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```